# Loading EXASOL data in R. Unknown ODBC error

Tags: r, rodbc, exasolution

R is unable to read the EXASOL Database due to some unknown ODBC error. Has anyone come across a similar instance. The problem occurs with Mac OS.

I have installed the ODBC driver for Mac OS.

```
library(exasol)
library(RODBC)

con <- dbConnect("exasol", **)
# removed the connection credentials 

df1 <- dbGetQuery(con,paste("query", sep=""))
# removed the query

Error in try(.Call(C_asyncRODBCQueryFinish, slot, 1)) : 
  Unknown ODBC error
Error in exa.readData(conn, statement, ...) : 
  Could not allocate SQLAllocHandle (-2)
Error in exa.readData(conn, statement, ...) : Unknown ODBC error
```

The issue is at the moment unanswered here https://github.com/exasol/r-exasol/issues/32.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell more about the tools/drivers/components you use? Version numbers and the like?

I have some faint memories of seeing the same (or very similar error message) when I tried to use `unixodbc`. I had to remove it and use `libiodbc`. May it be the source of the issue in your case?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, what helped me was to reinstall `install.packages("RODBC", type="source")`